# What is the purpose of this PLC circuit?

Tags: noise, schematics, industrial

I am reverse engineering the PLC I/O module. One output consists of a smart switch with three additional components.
Obviously, this is some kind of protection.

How does it work?

[image: circuit]

Updated:

[image: circuit]

PCB photo:

[image: pcb]

Comment: The labels on your switch are very confusing, it should be consistent with the datasheet, in, out, and Vbb.

Comment: I have updated the circuit.

Comment: The second one just looks like protection for inductive loads, the third one is indicative of the load (which should be resistive). I'm not sure what the cap is for, probably just some filtering.

Comment: I think thats not about clamping overvoltage either from inductive load nor from external supply. Freewheeling diode should be connected with cathode to OUT pin of the switch not to the ground. In this circuit diode is biased forward when switch is active... Also current through diode is limited to dozen of microamps. Demagnetizing inductive loads with such small current make no sense in my understanding.

Comment: It's a snubber, to dump inductive load spikes, except that diode should be swapped, check the polarity, it shouldn't be like depicted. Also the resistor 100k is too much.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Not that much. It's just there to discharge the capacitor so it would take 5ms. Just don't turn on and off the switch more frequently than that.

Comment: Looks like the R-D is there just to keep the C discharged on the next turn-on cycle (or even an eventual load capacitance) and assure the turn-on will start (nearly) effectively at the diode direct voltage, maximum. In that sense, the absence of the diode wouldn't make a significant change, but maybe they didn't want an intervention on negative pulses at the output (inductive load?) - even though in that case the internal D of the switch would intervene first (and decisively).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: added a little more information and made it more accurate.

BTS4140 is a a high side load switch that consists of an active low input, power supply input and output terminal. A load would be connected to output with power supply connect to Vbb terminal. When input pin is pull low, the internal control circuit which consists of a charge pump, will produce a voltage on gate of internal mosfet that is sufficiently higher than output terminal (essentially the source pin of that mosfet). Doing this causes the internal mosfet to turn on with practically low voltage between its drain to source terminals thus connecting Vbb to Vout.

output protection circuit  is a RCD snubber circuit aka a RCD clamp. Though by the looks of it it isn’t drawn right. 
That capacitor, resistor, and diode form a circuit that will safely clamp (ie limit)  inductive kickback in the case that load is inductive. That is When the internal MOSFET turns off, the RCD will prevent voltage across drain to source terminal from rising to a level that will damage MOSFET.  Diode ensures unidirectional current flow, R dissipates energy, and C stores energy. Usually though, R and C Are in parallel and then connected in series with diode but it would all be reversed with anode of diode at ground.

Source: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/8/848.html

http://electronicsbeliever.com/snubber-circuit-design-analysis/

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking how the switch works...

Comment: Yeah I Read the question too quick and decided to explain it. Little extra info can’t hurt.

Comment: I also thought about RCD snubber, but the value of the resistor is really strange, as @Marko Buršič mentioned.
I checked the circuit a few more times and asked a colleague to double-check it. The circuit is drawn exactly correctly. Attached a photo of PCB for clarity.